# escape delimiter in extjs 5.0.1 tagfield

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Is there any way by which we can escape the delimiter (for e.g. ",") in extjs tagfield. Basically i want to type the string which contains the delimiter character.

[image]

As we can see above, i want to type the string containing comma(i.e. ,) character. but as soon as i type comma it converts it into tag.

I am using the tagfield for allowing the user to input multiple values. The tagfield is associated with empty store.

Comment: Maybe you can just change `delimiter ` value for your field?

Comment: that might not help since the requirement is to allow users to type multiple comma separated values.